# No preview of images (Thunderbird)

Tags: thunderbird, previews

How can I see previews of images, if I want to attach a file to a mail in thunderbird?

My "file open" dialog looks like this:

[image: no-preview-of-images]

There are several images files with file extension ".jpg".

I would like to see the preview of all images file at once.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04

If I use nautilus, I see the previews. That's how I would like it to be:

[image: preview-with-images]